# Vee-validate with yup nested object not showing errors (not validating nested objects)

Tags: vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

So I have this setup using `vee-validate` and `yup`.

```
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate'
import * as yup from 'yup'

const {
  values,
  errors,
  defineComponentBinds,
  isSubmitting,
  setFieldValue,
  handleSubmit
} = useForm({
  validationSchema: yup.object({
    field0: yup.string().label('Field 0').required(),
    testFields: yup.object().shape({
      field1: yup.string().label('Field 1').required()
    })
  })
})

const field0 = defineComponentBinds('field0')
const testFields = ref({
  field1: defineComponentBinds('field1')
})
```

In my template:

```
<pre>{{ field0 }}</pre>
<InputText
 v-bind="field0"
 class="w-full border-left-3 border-red-600"
/>
<pre>{{ testFields }}</pre>
<InputText
 v-bind="testFields.field1"
 class="w-full border-left-3 border-red-600"
/>
```

The problem is `field1` which is inside the object `testFields` is not showing errors even it is set to `required()`. Upon testing to top level, `field0` works just fine. I don't know what I have missed but it seems the nested input is not validating properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A silly mistake. This should be:

```
const field1 = defineComponentBinds('testFields.field1')
<InputText
 v-bind="field1"
 class="w-full border-left-3 border-red-600"
/>
```

or (if you are working with dynamic fields)

```
const testFields = ref({
  field1: defineComponentBinds('testFields.field1')
})
<InputText
 v-bind="testFields.field1"
 class="w-full border-left-3 border-red-600"
/>
```

As the documentation stated [here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/nested-objects-and-arrays/)